# jQuery and PHP session issue

Tags: php, jquery, variables, uploadify

In uploadify I have a problem passing variable into the php script. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#uploadify").uploadify({

        'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'scripts/uploadify.php?upload',
        'scriptData'     : {'PHPSESSID' : '<? echo session_id(); ?>','counter' : counter},
        'cancelImg'      : 'cancel.png',
        'folder'         : 'uploads',
        'auto'           : true,
        'multi'          : false,
        'buttonText'     : 'Browse Image',
        onComplete: function(evt, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            loadPhotos();
            counter = $(".upload-photo").size();
            alert("Success: "+counter+" Response: "+response);
        }
    });
});
```

In onComplete response var should return the value of $_REQUEST['counter']. It returns 0 because counter = 0 in the beginning but it is not updating at:

```
counter = $(".upload-photo").size();
```

I also tried to pass the variable like this:

```
$("#uploadify").uploadifySettings("scriptData", {'counter' : $(".upload-photo").size()});
```

But it didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does the loadPhotos function do?.. does it have asynchronous calls?  Sounds to me like the .upload-photo object still has size 0 when the alert runs.

Comment: function loadPhotos() {
 $("#content_photos").load("scripts/uploadify.php?show");
}

Comment: loadPhotos function executes script with set variable show. This piece of code is responsible for outputting html with img tags that have a class="upload-photo"

Comment: `counter = ($(".upload-photo").length>0)?$(".upload-photo").length:'still 0';` try that and let me know what does your alert say ?

Comment: btw jquery recommends using .length instead of size as it's "slighly faster"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I was doing wrong but after some time spent tinkering sessions started working fine. Thank you every each of you for help.